# Value type of "Any" has no member 'objectforKey' Swift 3 conversion

Tags: swift

I am currently facing this problem **(Value type of "Any" has no member 'objectforKey')** due to swift 3 upgrade. Anybody knows why?

Here is my line of code that have the error

```
            let bookName:String  = (accounts[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).objectForKey("bookName") as! String
```

*accounts is an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay basically it is the .objectForKey needs to be change as the following:

```
    let bookName:String  = (accounts[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).object(forKey:"bookName") as! String
```

Answer (score 2):

As always, **do not** use `NS(Mutable)Array` / `NS(Mutable)Dictionary` in Swift. Both types lack type information and return `Any` which is the most unspecified type in Swift.

Declare `accounts` as Swift Array

```
var accounts = [[String:Any]]()
```

Then you can write

```
let bookName = accounts[indexPath.row]["bookName"] as! String
```

Another **Dont**: Do not annotate types that the compiler can infer.